# VBA Dynamically Filter Multi-Column Table Using Column of Product Numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to filter a data table of products as I type a product # into an Active X Control listbox.

I named the data table (found in the Design tab which is visible upon having focus on the table) 'Item' and linked an empty cell 'A1' (not positive what this does but know I need to do it for this solution to work) in the listbox properties. I then wrote the following macro:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Item").AutoFilter , Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & CStr(Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value) & ""
```

After typing the macro I exit Design Mode and go ahead typing in the listbox. If my list of product IDs looked liked this:

101
205
309
413
517

If I type 10 in the listbox, I would like all rows whose product number starts with 10 to remain in the table. However, the only thing this macro is allowing me to do is type the exact product number and then it will display that row.

I tried adding a * in the "" following the string value in the Criteria but this did not work to make the Criteria 'begins with'.

How can I modify my code to make the search filter as I type a product number to show rows whose product numbers start with the number I have typed?

Comment: Linked cell normally just displays the index of the currently selected item in the list i.e. 1 if the first, 2 if the second etc. If you change this cell, it is reflected in the listbox i.e. if you select 2, the second listbox item will be selected.

Comment: Sounds like you might be after something more like this..https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-adding-a-dependent-list-control-to-an-excel-sheet/

Comment: Thank you both for responding, it should be noted though that neither of these answers the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Add an “=“ at the beginning of your Criteria and an asterisk at its end

```
Range("Item").AutoFilter , Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & CStr(Range("A1").Value) & "*"
```

See I omit ”ActiveSheet” since it’s implicitly assumed

But you’d better always explicitly qualify your ranges up to workbook and worksheet references like:

```
With WorkBooks("MyWorkbookName").WorkSheets("MySheetName")
    .Range("Item").AutoFilter , Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & CStr(.Range("A1").Value) & "*"
End With
```